# UnsatisfiableError without the reason

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, conda

I found a couple of posts which had the same error but mine is different as it doesn't display any packages which were found to be incompatible [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr3LG.png)

I was trying to install tensorflow with the gpu

Error

```
(tf) C:\Users\Arbitrary>conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying 
with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from 
current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying             
with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abor|
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be 
incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
```

Comment: Please paste your code/errors as text, not as images.

Comment: According to the [tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native), version 2.10 was the last version that supported Windows native. If you want to use a newer version you'll have to install it into Windows WSL, or use `tensorflow-cpu`

Comment: How do i install it into Windows WSL?

Comment: FIXED IT BY WATCHING A YOUTUBE VIDEO